# How can I filter documents from a collection by a string type field named "fecha_proximo_mantenimiento" (next_date_maintenance)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, filter

I have a collection called "inventory_devices" and from this I need to get the documents that are close to maintenance (usually 30 days before the next maintenance date) and at the moment I am trying to filter the documents that are in the field "date_close_to_maintenance" 30 days before the date and I can't find the way to do it. "maintenance_next_date" is String type. I currently use the Mongoose library for MongoDB queries in NodeJS.

The variable/field "contract" is the common identifier that the documents have and it is the one that serves me to group them. Each X number of documents have a contract associated, something like a "Customer type" of a customer table.

The model has the following, I will show the data that are used only because the model could take 300 rows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema
    const InventarioDispositivosSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        contrato: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Contrato'
            },
      informacion_equipo: {
            type: Object,
            require: ["sistema_operativo", "ip", "nombre_equipo", "usuario_red"],
            properties: {
      ususario_red: { //Este campo y el modelo en sí funciona como está
                    type: String,
                    required: false,
                    trim: true,
                },
        },
    },fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
    }, { collection: 'inventario_dispositivos', timestamps: true })

const InventarioDispositivos = mongoose.model('InventarioDispositivos', InventarioDispositivosSchema)

module.exports = InventarioDispositivos
```

I have the following query:

```
// With "contrato" burned

let contrato = 'contrato1';

 Dispositivos.find(
  {
    //Filtros que se le hacen a la consulta 
    contrato,
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: {   
      $exists: true
    }
  },
  {
    //Datos que quiero que se muestren, solo el ID se oculta.
    _id: 0,
    'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
  }
).limit(10).then((devices) => {
  console.log(devices)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

A sample of the model shown and what the above query returns:

```
 {
    informacion_equipo: { ususario_red: 'angel.goez' },
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: '2021-08-30'
  },
  {
    informacion_equipo: { ususario_red: 'angel.goez' },
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: '2021-08-25'
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

The query below will filter documents that have `fecha_proximo_mantenimiento` with value older than 30 days.

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fecha_proximo_mantenimiento_timestamp": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$$NOW",
          {
            "$toDate": "$fecha_proximo_mantenimiento"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fecha_proximo_mantenimiento_timestamp": {
        "$gte": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
      }
    }
  }
]
```

First stage `$addFields` adds new field (I called same as original with appended `_timestamp` and it subtracts field value (which is also converted to Date, since your schema defined that as String) from Date.

Second stage `$match` checks that subtracted result (in miliseconds) is greater than 30 days (you can also replace with `2592000000` if it's easier for you).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need the date lower than 30 days of fecha_proximo_mantenimiento_timestamp. I will try it and see if it works with 30 greater than 30 dyas

Comment: I'm getting this error: MongooseError [ObjectParameterError]: Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: This only works with .aggregate? Or works with .find too?

Comment: If I use $lte instead of $gte, I can get 30 days lower than fecha_proximo_maintenance_timestamp_?

Comment: A lot of questions there. Yes, if it’s lower, then it should be $lte instead, my bad. This works only with aggregate since it requires multiple steps/stages. The error you’re getting is for TypeScript, not Mongoose.

Comment: I tried it again and it brings two registers, one with the following date: '2021-08-25' (It's an expired date) and the other with the following date: ''2021-08-25" (It's a valid date, so this is the only date that it had to bring to me) I try it with .aggrgate and filtering with $gte, with $lte brings an empty collection of documents. And the error on console show that is for mongoose, I didn't edit anything :c

Comment: You have provided two same dates. With those dates, I think $lte should find both of these. If you don't have those, then there might an issue somewhere else. Since I don't see an error, I can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: The valid date was 2021-08-30, my bad

Comment: It was my fault, is 30 days after the system date. My apologies to you, your function works so well!

Answer (score 0):

```
const hasta = moment(new Date()).add(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const desde = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

const contrato= 0;

Dispositivos.find(
  contrato,
  fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: { 
    $exists: true 
  }
},
  {
    _id: 0,
    'informacion_equipo.ususario_red': 1,
    fecha_proximo_mantenimiento: 1
  })
  .where('fecha_proximo_mantenimiento')
  .gte(desde)
  .lte(hasta)
  .exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      for (var x in result) {
        console.log('numero de documento: ', x, result[x])
      }
    }
  });
```

It works too with find